# Populate Dropdownlist items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

We're generating a dropdownlist in ASP.NET repeater as below -

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQty" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0" Selected="True" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So there are several dropdownlists generated on the page. For all these lists, I am trying to populate items containing values from `1 to 10`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var ddlQty = jQuery("select[id$='ddlQty']");                
    jQuery.each(ddlQty, function () {
        var curDdl = jQuery(this).next();            
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            curDdl.append(jQuery('<option>', { value: i, text: i }));
    });
});
```

This code doesn't work, Can you please help.

Thank You !

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all your respones, the issue lied in, `generating ID of repeaters`, repeaters controls ID were replaced by ***ddlQty_0, so I must use contains wild card in jQuery.

**Fixed Code.**

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

```
var ddlQty = jQuery("select[id*='ddlQty']");

jQuery.each(ddlQty, function () {
    var curDdl = jQuery(this);
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        curDdl.append(jQuery('<option>', { value: i, text: i }));
});
```

});

Comment: Why do you use `.next()` in `var curDdl = jQuery(this).next();`. You have selected the drop down.. Now just need to add options as child elements.

Comment: You said you are using asp.net repeater to show dropdownlist, there might be issue with binding data to all dropdownlists with same id. You may have to get repeater id and loop through each dropdowns and bind options to each not just one like you are doing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
var curDdl = jQuery(this).next();
```

with:

```
var curDdl = jQuery(this);
```

You don't need to be working on the next element in the DOM but with the current element which is the dropdown.

Also your code could be simplified a bit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('select[id$="ddlQty"]').each(function() {
        var curDdl = jQuery(this);
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            curDdl.append(jQuery('<option>', { value: i, text: i }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When I inspect var ddlQty in debugger, length is zero. I believe, this should be number of dropdown lists on the page, right?

Comment: Yeap, it seems that the selector is not matching any elements. That's weird as it seems fine to me. What's the exact id of the DropDown in the generated HTML markup?

Comment: What about the following selector: `jQuery('select')`? Are you getting any elements? Alternatively you could try adding a CssClass to those DropDowns and using a css selector: `$('.myddl')`. Or put them in a div tag with a fixed id: `<div id="mydiv">...</div>` and then use `jQuery('#mydiv select')`.

Comment: Hi Darin, issue lied in generation of control id inside repeaters, fixed. thanks for your help.